# How to write to a csv from from python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

I am web scraping with python from pacsun.com and I am trying to put it into a csv file but when I open the file only the headers print and not the product_name, price, or the new_arrival.

So my question is how do I get these values to print out under the headers in a csv file?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

my_url = ('https://www.pacsun.com/mens/')

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

product_data = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'product-data'})


#print(len(product_data))
#print(product_data[0])
product = product_data[0]

filename = 'pacsun.csv'
f = open(filename,'w')

headers = 'product_name, price, new_arrival\n'

f.write(headers)

for product in product_data:
    #name = product.div.a["title"]
    product_name = print('product: ' + product.div.a["title"])
    #the code above gets the title of the product
    price = product.findAll('div',{'class':'product-price group'})
    #the code above gets the price of the product
    new_arrival = product.findAll('div',{'class':'new'})
    #the code above gets

    print(price[0].text)
    print(new_arrival[0].text)


thewriter = csv.DictWriter(filename, headers)
thewriter.writerow({'product_name':product_name, 'price':price, 'new_arrival':new_arrival})



#f.write(product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + price + ","+ new_arrival + "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: Try to change it to `f = open(filename,'a')` and put `f.write` in the loop

Comment: I tried that and it prints the header twice

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the data. So, I fix it and it works fine. You only need to change `w` to  `a` to be `f = open(filename,'a')` and to put `f.write` in the loop

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
my_url = ('https://www.pacsun.com/mens/')


uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

product_data = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'product-data'})


#print(len(product_data))
#print(product_data[0])
product = product_data[0]

filename = 'pacsun.csv'
f = open(filename,"a")
headers = 'product_name, price, new_arrival\n'

f.write(headers)

for product in product_data:
    #name = product.div.a["title"]
    product_name = print('product: ' + product.div.a["title"])
    #the code above gets the title of the product
    price = product.findAll('div',{'class':'product-price group'})
    #the code above gets the price of the product
    new_arrival = product.findAll('div',{'class':'new'})
    price_ = ''
    new_arrival_ = ''
    product_name_ = ''
    # product_name_ = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in  product.div.a["title"]])
    for price_text in price:
        price_ = price_text.text
    for new_arrival_text in new_arrival:
        new_arrival_ = new_arrival_text.text


    f.write(product.div.a["title"]+","+price_+ "," + new_arrival_ + "\n")

f.close()
```